# pytorch object too deep for array when saving image

Tags: python, matplotlib, pytorch

I am trying to run the code from the following github rep:

https://github.com/iamkrut/image_inpainting_resnet_unet

I havent changed anything in the code and it is causing a ValueError, that the object is too deep, when the code tries to save the image. The error seems to come from these two lines.

```
images = img_tensor.cpu().detach().permute(0,2,3,1)
plt.imsave(join(data_dir, 'samples', image), images[index,:,:,:3])
```

Here is the error statement

```
  File "train.py", line 205, in <module>
    data_dir=args.data_dir)
  File "train.py", line 94, in train_net
    plt.imsave(join(data_dir, 'samples', image), images[index,:,:,:]);
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\torch2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 2140, in imsave
    return matplotlib.image.imsave(fname, arr, **kwargs)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\torch2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py", line 1498, in imsave
    _png.write_png(rgba, fname, dpi=dpi)
ValueError: object too deep for desired array
```

Anyone know what could be causing this or how to fix it?
Thank you

Comment: Can you add the error statement you are getting in the terminal?

Comment: Yeah just added it

Comment: Can you print the shape of images[index,:,:,:3]?

Comment: I used len() instead of shape I hope that doesnt matter. torch.Size([128, 128, 4]) @nsidn98

Comment: I checked today with .shape and it gave torch.Size([128, 128, 3]). I think i was looking at the wrong line sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

matplotlib package does not understand the pytorch datatype (tensor). you should convert tensor array to numpy array and then use matplotlib functions.

```
a = torch.rand(10, 3, 20, 20)
plt.imsave("test.jpg", a.cpu().detach().permute(0, 2, 3, 1)[0, ...]) # Error
plt.imsave("test.jpg", a.cpu().detach().permute(0, 2, 3, 1).numpy()[0, ...])
```

Comment: I am guessing that is what I did in my answer just with less steps correct?

Comment: I answered your question "Still not sure what was wrong with the previous version". Your first code is wrong, because you are using tensor array as input of the imsave. matplotlib accepts ndarray.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix the code by changing the lines to

```
images=img_tensor.cpu().numpy()[0]
images = np.transpose(images, (1,2,0))
plt.imsave(join(data_dir, 'samples', image), images)
```

Still not sure what was wrong with the previous version. So if anyone knows please tell me.